# Web Service Setter not working

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I have this Web Service class running on Tomcat 8.5 and Axis2 in Eclipse:

```
public int volumen = 0, led = 0;
public String ultimaFecha = "null";

public int Volumen() {
    return volumen;
}

public String Fecha() {
    return LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
}

public String Ultima() {
    return ultimaFecha;
}

public int LED() {
    System.out.println("LED: " + this.led);
    return led;
}

public void setLED(int led) {
    System.out.println("Old LED: " + this.led);
    this.led = led;
    System.out.println("New LED: " + this.led);
    ultimaFecha = Fecha();
}
```

When I try to call the `setLED(int led)`method, it seems to work properly, displaying that the result was updated correctly, but when I call the getter `LED()`, it returns me the initial 0 value. On C#:

```
SensorServices.Sensor s = new SensorServices.Sensor();
s.setLED(30);
var result = s.LED();
```

result's value is 0. In Tomcat, the print's shows the above:

```
Old LED: 0
New LED: 30
LED: 0
```

What is going on? Why am I unable to update the variable's value? How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using the same instance of `SensorServices.Sensor`?

Comment: It's impossible. `New LED: 30` shows that the value is changed. Are you doing something in between?

Comment: The instance hasn't changed at all because I'm calling both service's methods from the same client-method's scope. Plus, I also tried to create a static single instance of the object and it didn't work either. The Java Class is as it's shown below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to do some shitty solution but it worked for me.

It seems that every time I call any method from my client a new instance is created in the server, so I put everything static and worked like a charm. I think that I only need one instance so the static variables did the trick.

Comment: Making the variable static is hiding the problem instead of solving it. As you stated, it seems like you are creating a new instance every time you call the method. That is the problem. Doing this will slow down your program, eat up memory and cause issues like the one mentioned in your question. You need to solve that issue and your original question will be fixed. You probably need to move `SensorServices.Sensor s = new SensorServices.Sensor();` to a different class or method.

Comment: @TotZam The problem is not with the client, but with the server. Every time you try to access any method from the Sensor's class, Apache creates a new instance and deletes all my previously saved values. I couldn't find any way to solve this apart from my approach and maybe use a Singleton (something that I haven't tried). If you have any another solution in the server-side, please let me know.